# Adding Custom Paramenter to add product

Tags: product, price

i want to add custom parameter to product say quality:A,B,C
with different additional prices like A(10), B(15), C(5)

Now when user selects A product will be added to cart with price + 10
i also want to show A in admin order detail.

How can i do this via module / observer.

Pls help , its new for me

below code does not works

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mour_Customgroup>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mour_Customgroup>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <setadiscountprice>
                    <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observe</class>
                    <method>modifyPrice</method>
                </setadiscountprice>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
  </frontend>
</config> 

<?php
class Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observe
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }


        // This makes sure the discount isn't applied over and over when refreshing
        $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() +10;

        // Make sure we don't have a negative
        if ($specialPrice > 0) {
            $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mour.you can do this magento event observer.

When you cart a product then fire event `an event  and on this observer to you edit cart item price`.

I suggest you use `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

Observer.php

```
public function applyDiscount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */

    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }


    // This makes sure the discount isn't applied over and over when refreshing
    $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() +10;

    // Make sure we don't have a negative
    if ($specialPrice > 0) {
        $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah but how can i get weather A , B or C is selected

Comment: it this apply for all products.... you want for special one product you need put condition observer

Comment: yeah it apply for some category only 
what code should i write to check value selected a,b or c ?..

Comment: you have get product id then using product you can get categories ids then put your code

Comment: yeah but i want to get selected dropdown value also, its dropdown of quality with value a,b,c i want to get value of dropdown

Comment: i have updated code but it does not works see

Comment: Is A,B,C  is a associated product  or simple product

Comment: it is my mistake.please change  $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
 to
 $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

Comment: @saravanavelu a,b,c is just dropdown custom

Comment: that means you have a product which have 3 option on drop if i select then  price will + option price? is this correct?

Comment: yeah exactly ..but it's still not working

Comment: its working but it update all other items in cart with new values selected

Answer (score 1):

you can try with  **checkout_cart_save_after** instead of **checkout_cart_product_add_after**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mour_Customgroup>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mour_Customgroup>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_save_after>
            <observers>
                <setadiscountprice>
                    <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observe</class>
                    <method>modifyPrice</method>
                </setadiscountprice>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_save_after>
    </events>
  </frontend>
</config> 

<?php
class Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer
{
    public function modifyPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();

        $quoteitems = $quote->getAllItems(); (or) $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($quoteitems as $item) {
            /*@var $quoteItem Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
           $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() +10;
            foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId){
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
                $categoryname  = $category->getName();
                //set the products to particular category and check the condition
                if($categoryname == "dress")// for example your category is dress
                {
                    if ($specialPrice > 0) {
                        $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

or

try the below code, it works good.Please clear cache and check.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                /*@var $quoteItem Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
                $product = $item->getProduct();
                $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
               $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() +10;
                foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId){
                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
                    $categoryname  = $category->getName();
                    //set the products to particular category and check the condition
                    if($categoryname == "dress")// for example your category is dress
                    {
                        if ($specialPrice > 0) {
                            $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        $quote->save();
```

Comment: not working getting same product price –

Comment: I have tried the second code, it works goods